# Prototype spring bean giving me only one instance of the class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am currently learning Spring boot. As in the code, I have written the scope annotation with prototype bean.

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public class ninja {
    // constructor
    public ninja() {
        System.out.println("object created");
    }
}
```

I expect it to let me create multiple objects whenever I call the getBean function.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // creating first instance
        ninja obj = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args).getBean(ninja.class);

        // creating second instance
        ninja obj1 = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args).getBean(ninja.class);

    }

}
```

But I am only getting one instance after calling getBean() for two times, Object created is a text being printed by the constructor, it should be printed twice.

[image]

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are basically initializing the spring application twice. So, you will get a **different application context each time**. Change it like below and look at the output :

```
ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

Ninja obj = getBean(Ninja.class);
Ninja obj1 = getBean(Ninja.class);
```

Note: I have changed the name as per java naming convention and I advise you to follow the same.

Answer (score 0):

Prototype will only create another object if the target object which you're injecting into is different. Since you're injecting twice in the same method, you'll get the same instance. Try making a factory that is prototype scoped and inject this factory instead.

Comment: Hello the scope prototype is mean to create a new instance each time you call it (no matter the use of factory).  The problem here is more because she create application Context twice

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are calling it from the same class, if you wanted to see how prototype scope works you can do this:

1. Create 2 Controllers with @RestController
2. Create 1 Service with : @Service and @Scope("prototype")
3. Have each Controller with @Autowired with a field of that service type.

In this example, each controller will get a different instance of the class defined as the Service. You can test this by calling #hashCode inside the Service method.